# What is the standard formatting for figures being in the left margin? (Or column?)

Tags: formatting, margins, geometry

I've noticed that a lot of math textbooks have a small right margin and a large left margin, so that they can put figures, along with captions and notes in the left margin. I'm wondering what the standard width the `textwidth` should have, the `left`  and `right` margins should have, the `marginparwidth`, and the `marginparsep` should have, so that I can set them with the `geometry` package? (For 8.5inx11in paper). Or even is there a standard size? I would then use the `sidenotes` package to place figures in the margins.

I'm also wondering what the best way to do this is. Should I use the `geometry` package and set all those lengths, or should I make my document have somehow two columns, so that I wouldn’t really change the margin dimensions much? I've heard this can be done with the packages `multicol` or `paracol`, and some others. Should I be using those? If I used one of those packages, I'd want to be able to mostly use the right column (with my main text) and leave spaces in the second column until I want to put a figure there, as if the left column was just margin notes, and I could choose exactly where in that column to put figures.

Some pictures that demonstrate what I want to achieve are below:

[image]

Notice how in the image below there is a long space between the figures in the left margin with no text; that’s what I’d like to be able to do:

[image: Notice how this one has a long space between the figures with no text.]

And this image below has the “Examples” in the left margin (or column):

[image]

Does anyone know how these books are formatted? My math proofs are not books though, they are short, so I normally just use the `article` class. Thanks!

Comment: The [tufte classes](https://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex) have this style by default (but with figures in the right margin), see the [example document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/sample-handout.pdf) on CTAN.

Comment: I don’t really like the tufte-classes though, for one the larger margins are on the right side, not left, and the title formatting is weird and hard to adjust. The tufte-classes aren’t what I’m looking for, I’ve already tried those before.

Comment: That's ok, it was just a suggestion in case you didn't know the class existed.

Comment: Yes, thanks anyway though.

Comment: You can use paracol to create two columns with diferrent widths.  Note that `\textwidth` encompasses both columns.

Comment: Okay, but do you know if that’s what I should use to format papers as in the examples I gave?

Comment: For a journal, they will specify the format.  Otherwise, do whatever you want.